# Overlapped appendices in Table of contents and List of figure

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I'm see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/190817/overlapped-appendices-in-table-of-contents) to indent the chapters of my appendix as sections in the table of contents but it's not working

My code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\appendix

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.\Roman{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}  
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A.\Roman{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}

\input{anexo}
  inside many figures
more imput...
\end{document}
```

And i get

[image]

And for list of figures

[image]

I dont know how to fix it

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  does this question help: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415) ?

Comment: Hi. I still have the problem. I find tocloft and this is the code i need:
           \renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em}
But i want to only apply in appendix. I insert the code after \appendix but it's not working

Comment: you need to force that line into the relevant toc file in the appropriate place.  at the top of your file `anexo.tex` place this line: `\addtocontents{toc}{\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em}}` and similarly for `{lof}`.  it must be *in* the file with the appendix material.  i know that if it's placed in a "calling" file and the "text" file is called with `\include`, the `\addtocontents` is delayed until after that file has been input; i'm not sure about the ordering if `\input` is used, but it's better not to take a chance.

Comment: It's not working. i think that i can change the name in table of content with \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Anexo \Roman{chapter}} but i do not know how hide A.I Anexo

Comment: you want the entries for the appendix entries to be omitted?  the question seems to ask something different -- that space be made so that the section numbers don't overlap.  but the principle is the same.  you have to insert something into the `.toc` (or `.lof`, etc.) file in the appropriate place.

Comment: I want the extra space in the table of contents and in the list of figures and tables to eliminate the overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the changes of the `numwidth` boxes in the ToC, LoF and LoT should be restricted to some part of the document, the `\addtolength{cftchapnumwidth}{10pt}` etc. has to be written literally into the relevant ToC - file.

Please note that this might produce inconsistent layout in the ToCs.

The value of `40pt` is of course too large, I have used it just for demonstration.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{pgffor}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\clearpage

% 
\chapter{Regular content}
\foreach \x in {1,...,10} {%
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure caption \x}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table caption \x}
\end{table}
}


\clearpage
\appendix


\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addtolength{\protect\cftchapnumwidth}{10pt}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addtolength{\protect\cftfignumwidth}{40pt}}
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addtolength{\protect\cfttabnumwidth}{40pt}}




\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A.\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}  
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}



%\input{anexo}

\chapter{Appendix content One}


\foreach \x in {1,...,10} {%
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Figure caption \x}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Table caption \x}
\end{table}
}

\chapter{Appendix content Two}

\foreach \x in {1,...,10} {%
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Figure caption \x}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Table caption \x}
\end{table}
}



\end{document}
```

[image]