# Append \appendixname to \subsection doesn't work properly

Tags: appendices, appendix

I am new to LaTeX.

**Using:** `\usepackage[title,toc,titletoc,page]{appendix}`

**My LaTeX:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[title,toc,titletoc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\glsaddall 

\newpage
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\appendixname}{\Alph{subsection}}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\begin{appendices}

\subsection{Projects}
\subsection{Interview}
\subsection{Data}
\subsection{Samples}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

**Results in**:
[image]

***Not sure how this can be resolved and fixed with formatting.***

EDIT: Followed the following sample, https://gist.github.com/X4/7759575

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, possibly starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. This being said, what are you trying to do with `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\appendixname}{\Alph{subsection}}`? `\renewcommand` takes only two arguments.

Comment: Please double check the `{}`'s in that sample with the number you use.  The sample you refer to is correct, yours is not.

Comment: @daleif, I tried this. `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\appendixname~\Alph{subsection}}`

Comment: the second problem is that there is not enough room for \thesubsection inside \numberline.  There should be a way to adjust \numberline using titletoc.  I know it can be changed by NOT using titletoc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, how exactly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width for `\numberline` is normally passed using `\@tempdima` which is set locally. To change the width in the middle of the toc requires the use of `\addtocontents`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[title,toc,titletoc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{listings}

\newlength{\appwidth}
\settowidth{\appwidth}{\appendixname}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\resetnumberline}{\def\numberline##1{%
  \advance\@tempdima by \appwidth
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{##1\hfil}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
%\glsaddall 

\newpage
\subsection{test}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\appendixname~\Alph{subsection}}%
\setcounter{section}{0}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\resetnumberline}%

\begin{appendices}

\subsection{Projects}
\subsection{Interview}
\subsection{Data}
\subsection{Samples}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

```
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\fixappendix}{%
  \patchcmd{\l@subsection}{2.3em}{5.6em}{}{}%
}
```

Source: [LaTeX: iopart and overlapping appendices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520516/latex-iopart-and-overlapping-appendices)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In order to make this a proper answer, please consinder adding a comment on how to use the above code snippet.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, I marked the other dude's response as an answer. As that also works.

Comment: No idea what that does or how to use it until I looked at your referenced source which was clear unlike your suggestion above. You only took code from one of the answers which seems a bit unfair. If you want to provide an answer please provide a complete one not an unusable snippet.